# Pandas: Variable precision for exporting to csv

Tags: pandas

How to set adjustable precision so that it self-adjusts depending on its value? This is to export to csv.

For example for the following values:

Set max precision to 18.

```
0.00748333333333333 -> 0.00748333333333
12.0000000 -> 12.0
0.43242300000 -> 0.432423
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use a regular expressions to replace unwanted zeros on the saved CSV file:

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x1':[*np.random.randn(5), *[2, 3, 1.25]],
    'x2':[*np.random.randn(5), *[2, 3, 1.25]],
})

# Save CSV file
csv_file_name = 'test.csv'
df.to_csv(csv_file_name, float_format="%0.8f") 

# Read CSV file
with open(csv_file_name, 'r') as file: 
    s = file.read()

# Replace zeros using regex
s = re.sub("[0]+\n", "\n", s)
s = re.sub("[0]+,", ",", s)

# Re-save CSV file
with open(csv_file_name, 'w') as file: 
    file.write(s)
```

Resulting CSV:

```
,x1,x2
,-0.48248428,0.37133094
1,-0.58110733,-1.08972915
2,-0.25407414,-0.83307601
3,-0.73887322,-0.37982818
4,0.11092894,0.93965402
5,2.,2.
6,3.,3.
7,1.25,1.25
```

Comment: You can do the same thing but without first dumping to the CSV. Just change the column types in `df` to string  then perform the same exact operations. I think that's a cleaner method because it only requires 1 writing of the csv via `to_csv` function